# Simulating an individual script timeout (or slow load) with Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timeout, google-chrome-devtools, throttling

I am trying to work out how to use Google Chrome DevTools to simulate a timeout on a JavaScript file on my site.

I can use the 'Toggle Device Mode' to introduce throttling but that doesn't target a specific script.

Is there a way to do this with DevTools?

I am using Chrome 38.

Answer (score 5):

DevTools technical writer and developer advocate here. As of January 2018:

- You can't network-throttle individual requests in DevTools. You can block them, though, which is what I assume you mean by "timeout". See [Block Requests](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=2018Q1#block-requests).
- You could use a [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) to network-throttle individual requests.

Haven't tested this code, but something like this might work for the service-worker-based throttling:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const TARGET = 'example.com';
  const DELAY_MS = 1000;
  if (event.request.url === TARGET) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request));
    }, DELAY_MS);
  }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, and injecting log statements within the callback and `if` block didn't output anything when the calls were fired. Is there some small tweak that would make this work in the latest version of Chrome (78.x)?

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome you can setup a new network profile with custom download/upload bandwidth and latency time.

Use a long enough latency value to trigger a request timeout.